# Tap on the tex in UILabel

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel

I have a UILabel. I would to detect a tap only on the text of this label.

For example, I have a UILabel very large with some text in the center.

Is possible this?
I can't add/use other UILabel or components.

Comment: hitTest ? can't you add a button over it? or use button instead?

Comment: No, I can't add other components. How can use hitTest in this situation?

Comment: to detect where exactly user tapped, why can't you add any component?

Answer (score 0):

Add UITapGestureRecongizer on the label:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *labelTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(actionForTap:)];
[yourLabel addGestureRecognizer:labelTap];
```

To make the tap active only on the text, set the uilabel text and then call:

```
[yourLabel sizeToFit]
```

in order to make the UILabel frame as big as the text.

Comment: and how you detect hitting text not the label outside the text?